# BeginUpdates and EndUpdates

Tags: ios, uitableview

Would there ever be a reason to call `beginUpdates` and immediately follow it with a call to `endUpdates` with nothing happening in between?

I ran across this in the code base I'm working on. The commit message associated with the code seems to do with adjusting spacing and height of tablecells when the device rotates.

But from what I understand from the docs, the purpose of the two methods are to batch execute changes to the datasource.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668046/uitableview-adaptive-cell-height, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066167/accordion-table-cell-how-to-dynamically-expand-contract-uitableviewcell There are probably others.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thanks maddy.